# Is it possible to make gradle a bit more transparent?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to use Android Studio. When I do a build I see a bunch of messages corresponding to tasks. Where are these tasks defined? Can you edit them? The whole process seems a little opaque.

Are there any IDE options or settings to open up the internals a little bit.
I've used --debug, and while that helps a bit, that seems to be the only option.

Comment: did you try checking the official user guide http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide ??

Comment: I suggest you should just go and read the gradle manual, it will help a lot...

Answer (score 0):

In build.gradle file there is a plugin for android

apply plugin 'android'

In that plugin everything is declared regarding android build.
There are other plugin as well like

apply plugin 'eclipse' etc
You can create your own plugin as well.